# Why is Nifi reporting an impossibly large queue size?

Tags: apache-nifi

We have a Nifi that's currently reporting that there are close to 4TB of messages in a queue. However, the nodes only have 500GB of space on each and none of the drives are full. I initially suspected that there was an issue with links where it could be counting the size of files multiple times, but there are no links in that directory. Most of the disk usage on the primary node (It's using the most space in the 3 node cluster) is in the flowfile_repository/swap/ directory and that directory is only 147G in size.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Do all queues do the same? Is this because of some compression being done at the flowfile level?

UPDATE: It looks like there was an infinite loop for failures that was not only replaying the messages, but also logging the failures, which is where the queue was backing up. In this case, I'm suspecting that since it was the same flowfile being replayed, Nifi was saving space by simply referencing the original flowfile vs. creating more copies. Is that a correct assumption? I'm just trying to understand exactly what happened.